# wsHttpBinding not supported by silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf, web-services

How do people typically do session with WCF if this binding isn't supported in silverlight?

Comment: I typically **never** do session with WCF..... what makes you think that is the "typical" case?? The recommended best practice is per-call, e.g. no session at all

Comment: The best case is that I make a 3rd party wcf for someone and want to keep it as easy as possible for them by abstracting data storage for them.  Is there a better way?

Comment: are you talking about WCF session or ASP .NET session? what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight supports [BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx) and [PollingDuplexHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.pollingduplexhttpbinding%28VS.95%29.aspx) (if you need duplex). Check out [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296254%28VS.95%29.aspx).